# Interlace video frames

Tags: compositing-nodes, video

I want to concatenate several video files into one. Say I have 4 files. I want the new video's first frame to be frame 1 of video 1, 2nd frame be frame 1 of video 2, 3rd frame to be frame 1 of video 3, etc, and then looping. Is there any way to do this, preferably in the compositor?